# How to pass the -D parameter when multiple WAR files are running?

Tags: java, tomcat

When multiple WAR files are running under tomcat,
each WAR is expecting a

```
-Dconfig-path=/path/app.conf.ini
```

Is it possible to pass a unique -D Parameter value to each of the running applications?

```
tomcat
   webapps
       APPLICATION_1.war  -Dconfig-path=/path/app.conf1.ini
       APPLICATION_2.war  -Dconfig-path=/path/app.conf2.ini
       APPLICATION_3.war  -Dconfig-path=/path/app.conf3.ini
```

Comment: No, it sets a JVM-wide system property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all the configuration properties in one file and pass it as command line parameter while starting tomcat. All those properties will be available to all .war files.

But if all the war files are using same property name then you have to modify the property name in config file and your code.

For example: If you are using app.version=1.1 for 1st war and 2.1 for 2nd war then you have to add them like

```
Firstwarname.app.version=1.1
SecondwarName.app.version=2.1
```

Accordingly, your code needs to be modified to access properties.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way
In the web.xml added this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>config-path</param-name>
    <param-value>/path/app.conf1.ini</param-value>
</context-param>
```